# How to sum different iteration values?

Tags: python

How do I sum all the values of X obtained for each iteration of k?

```
print('Enter value for N between 1 and 50:') #User inputs number for N
N=int(input())
k=1

if N < 1:
    print('N must be between 1 and 50')

while k <= N:
    if N < 50:
        x=(1/(2**k))    #Value X is calculated for each value of N
        print('x=', x) 
        k=k + 1       
    else:
        print('N must be between 1 and 50')
        break
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new variable named `sum` that starts at 0. And accumulate the value of `x` into it every time you have a new value for `x`.

```
print('Enter value for N between 1 and 50:') #User inputs number for N
N=int(input())
k=1
sum=0

if N < 1 or N > 50:
    print('N must be between 1 and 50')
    exit()

while k <= N:
    x=(1/(2**k))    #Value X is calculated for each value of N
    sum=sum+x
    print('x=', x) 
    k=k + 1       

print("Sum = ", sum)
```

Note that I also moved the verification for `N` before the loop, because you just need to check for that once.

Comment: Perfect! Although, I'm a bit picky. When the range wasn't correct the final print command still ran, resulting in a sum of 0 being printed. To stop this I added a Range variable that would equal 0 if N was outside the Range. Then, for the final sum print, only print if Range!=0. :)

Comment: I'd be surprised since I added an `exit` call which terminates the script. But hey you managed to get it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to be a bit more precise ? 
Do you want to have `x` displayed at each iteration, as is currently the case, and a global count at the end, summing all `x` ?

If this is the case, you could introduce an extra variable as below

```
print('Enter value for N between 1 and 50:') #User inputs number for N
N=int(input())
k=1

if N < 1:
    print('N must be between 1 and 50')

total_count = 0  # new variable
while k <= N:
    if N < 50:
        x=(1/(2**k))    #Value X is calculated for each value of N
        print('x=', x) 
        total_count += x # this updates the total count
        k=k + 1       
    else:
        print('N must be between 1 and 50')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though in an operation up to 50 it is not(commonly) needed, I'd use numpy to vectorize my answer.

```
import numpy as np

N=int(input('Enter value for N between 1 and 50: '))

if N < 1 or N > 50:
    print('N must be between 1 and 50')
else:
    x = 1/(2**np.arange(1, N+1, dtype=float))
    print(x)  # in case you want to know the value at each "iteration"
    sum = np.sum(x)
    print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Working on a proof for this but `1 - (1/2**N)` will also give you the answer.